# Forwarding to error page from request [/upload-img] due to exception [Failed to parse multi

Tags: amazon-web-services, spring-boot, ubuntu, file-upload, java-11

I am trying to upload an image and encountered the following error, within an application deployed on ubuntu using AWS LightSail.

```
o.s.b.w.servlet.support.ErrorPageFilter  : Forwarding to error page from request [/upload-img] due to exception [Failed to parse multipart servlet request; nested exception is java.io.IOException: org.apache.tomcat.util.http.fileupload.impl.IOFileUploadException: Processing of multipart/form-data request failed. /var/myuploads/upload_98120ffe_9eca_4a43_9fe7_c67f4a5f46b7_00000001.tmp (Read-only file system)] 
org.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartException: Failed to parse multipart servlet request; nested exception is java.io.IOException: org.apache.tomcat.util.http.fileupload.impl.IOFileUploadException: Processing of multipart/form-data request failed. /var/myuploads/upload_98120ffe_9eca_4a43_9fe7_c67f4a5f46b7_00000001.tmp (Read-only file system) 
at org.springframework.web.multipart.support.StandardMultipartHttpServletRequest.handleParseFailure(StandardMultipartHttpServletRequest.java:127) ~[spring-web-5.3.29.jar:5.3.29] 
at org.springframework.web.multipart.support.StandardMultipartHttpServletRequest.parseRequest(StandardMultipartHttpServletRequest.java:115) ~[spring-web-5.3.29.jar:5.3.29] 
at org.springframework.web.multipart.support.StandardMultipartHttpServletRequest.<init>(StandardMultipartHttpServletRequest.java:88) ~[spring-web-5.3.29.jar:5.3.29] 
at org.springframework.web.multipart.support.StandardServletMultipartResolver.resolveMultipart(StandardServletMultipartResolver.java:122) ~[spring-web-5.3.29.jar:5.3.29] 
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.checkMultipart(DispatcherServlet.java:1210) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.29.jar:5.3.29] 
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1044) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.29.jar:5.3.29] 
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:965) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.29.jar:5.3.29] 
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.29.jar:5.3.29] 
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:909) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.29.jar:5.3.29] 
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:660) ~[tomcat9-servlet-api.jar:na] 
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.29.jar:5.3.29] 
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741) ~[tomcat9-servlet-api.jar:na] 
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231) ~[tomcat9-catalina-9.0.31.jar:9.0.31] 
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat9-catalina-9.0.31.jar:9.0.31] 
at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53) ~[tomcat9-websocket-9.0.31.jar:9.0.31] 
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat9-catalina-9.0.31.jar:9.0.31] 
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat9-catalina-9.0.31.jar:9.0.31] 
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:337) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.10.jar:5.7.10] 
at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:115) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.10.jar:5.7.10] 
at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:81) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.10.jar:5.7.10] 
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:346) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.10.jar:5.7.10] 
at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:122) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.10.jar:5.7.10] 
at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:116) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.10.jar:5.7.10] 
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:346) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.10.jar:5.7.10] 
at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:126) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.10.jar:5.7.10] 
at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:81) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.10.jar:5.7.10] 
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:346) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.10.jar:5.7.10] 
at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:109) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.10.jar:5.7.10] 
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:346) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.10.jar:5.7.10] 
at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:149) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.10.jar:5.7.10] 
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:346) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.10.jar:5.7.10] 
at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:63) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.10.jar:5.7.10] 
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:346) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.10.jar:5.7.10] 
at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:223) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.10.jar:5.7.10] 
at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:217) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.10.jar:5.7.10] 
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:346) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.10.jar:5.7.10] 
at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:103) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.10.jar:5.7.10] 
at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:89) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.10.jar:5.7.10] 
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:346) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.10.jar:5.7.10] 
at org.springframework.web.filter.CorsFilter.doFilterInternal(CorsFilter.java:91) ~[spring-web-5.3.29.jar:5.3.29] 
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117) ~[spring-web-5.3.29.jar:5.3.29] 
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:346) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.10.jar:5.7.10] 
at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doHeadersAfter(HeaderWriterFilter.java:90) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.10.jar:5.7.10] 
at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:75) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.10.jar:5.7.10] 
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117) ~[spring-web-5.3.29.jar:5.3.29] 
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:346) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.10.jar:5.7.10] 
at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:112) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.10.jar:5.7.10] 
at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:82) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.10.jar:5.7.10] 
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:346) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.10.jar:5.7.10] 
at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:55) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.10.jar:5.7.10] 
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117) ~[spring-web-5.3.29.jar:5.3.29] 
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:346) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.10.jar:5.7.10] 
at org.springframework.security.web.session.DisableEncodeUrlFilter.doFilterInternal(DisableEncodeUrlFilter.java:42) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.10.jar:5.7.10] 
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117) ~[spring-web-5.3.29.jar:5.3.29] 
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:346) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.10.jar:5.7.10] 
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:221) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.10.jar:5.7.10] 
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:186) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.10.jar:5.7.10] 
at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:354) ~[spring-web-5.3.29.jar:5.3.29] 
at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:267) ~[spring-web-5.3.29.jar:5.3.29] 
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat9-catalina-9.0.31.jar:9.0.31] 
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat9-catalina-9.0.31.jar:9.0.31] 
at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100) ~[spring-web-5.3.29.jar:5.3.29] 
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117) ~[spring-web-5.3.29.jar:5.3.29] 
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat9-catalina-9.0.31.jar:9.0.31] 
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat9-catalina-9.0.31.jar:9.0.31] 
at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93) ~[spring-web-5.3.29.jar:5.3.29] 
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117) ~[spring-web-5.3.29.jar:5.3.29] 
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat9-catalina-9.0.31.jar:9.0.31] 
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat9-catalina-9.0.31.jar:9.0.31] 
at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.ErrorPageFilter.doFilter(ErrorPageFilter.java:126) ~[spring-boot-2.7.15.jar:2.7.15] 
at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.ErrorPageFilter.access$000(ErrorPageFilter.java:64) ~[spring-boot-2.7.15.jar:2.7.15] 
at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.ErrorPageFilter$1.doFilterInternal(ErrorPageFilter.java:101) ~[spring-boot-2.7.15.jar:2.7.15] 
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117) ~[spring-web-5.3.29.jar:5.3.29] 
at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.ErrorPageFilter.doFilter(ErrorPageFilter.java:119) ~[spring-boot-2.7.15.jar:2.7.15] 
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat9-catalina-9.0.31.jar:9.0.31] 
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat9-catalina-9.0.31.jar:9.0.31] 
at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201) ~[spring-web-5.3.29.jar:5.3.29] 
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117) ~[spring-web-5.3.29.jar:5.3.29] 
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat9-catalina-9.0.31.jar:9.0.31] 
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat9-catalina-9.0.31.jar:9.0.31] 
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:202) ~[tomcat9-catalina-9.0.31.jar:9.0.31] 
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96) ~[tomcat9-catalina-9.0.31.jar:9.0.31] 
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:541) ~[tomcat9-catalina-9.0.31.jar:9.0.31] 
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:139) ~[tomcat9-catalina-9.0.31.jar:9.0.31] 
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92) ~[tomcat9-catalina-9.0.31.jar:9.0.31] 
at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:688) ~[tomcat9-catalina-9.0.31.jar:9.0.31] 
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74) ~[tomcat9-catalina-9.0.31.jar:9.0.31] 
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343) ~[tomcat9-catalina-9.0.31.jar:9.0.31] 
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:375) ~[tomcat9-coyote-9.0.31.jar:9.0.31] 
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65) ~[tomcat9-coyote-9.0.31.jar:9.0.31] 
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:868) ~[tomcat9-coyote-9.0.31.jar:9.0.31] 
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1594) ~[tomcat9-coyote-9.0.31.jar:9.0.31] 
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) ~[tomcat9-coyote-9.0.31.jar:9.0.31] 
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128) ~[na:na] 
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628) ~[na:na] 
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) ~[tomcat9-util-9.0.31.jar:9.0.31] 
at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829) ~[na:na] 
Caused by: java.io.IOException: org.apache.tomcat.util.http.fileupload.impl.IOFileUploadException: Processing of multipart/form-data request failed. /var/myuploads/upload_98120ffe_9eca_4a43_9fe7_c67f4a5f46b7_00000001.tmp (Read-only file system) 
at org.apache.catalina.connector.Request.parseParts(Request.java:2917) ~[tomcat9-catalina-9.0.31.jar:9.0.31] 
at org.apache.catalina.connector.Request.getParts(Request.java:2772) ~[tomcat9-catalina-9.0.31.jar:9.0.31] 
at org.apache.catalina.connector.RequestFacade.getParts(RequestFacade.java:1098) ~[tomcat9-catalina-9.0.31.jar:9.0.31] 
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequestWrapper.getParts(HttpServletRequestWrapper.java:359) ~[tomcat9-servlet-api.jar:na] 
message repeated 3 times: [ #011at javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequestWrapper.getParts(HttpServletRequestWrapper.java:359) ~[tomcat9-servlet-api.jar:na]] 
at org.springframework.web.multipart.support.StandardMultipartHttpServletRequest.parseRequest(StandardMultipartHttpServletRequest.java:95) ~[spring-web-5.3.29.jar:5.3.29] 
... 95 common frames omitted 
Caused by: org.apache.tomcat.util.http.fileupload.impl.IOFileUploadException: Processing of multipart/form-data request failed. /var/myuploads/upload_98120ffe_9eca_4a43_9fe7_c67f4a5f46b7_00000001.tmp (Read-only file system) 
at org.apache.tomcat.util.http.fileupload.FileUploadBase.parseRequest(FileUploadBase.java:297) ~[tomcat9-coyote-9.0.31.jar:9.0.31] 
at org.apache.catalina.connector.Request.parseParts(Request.java:2870) ~[tomcat9-catalina-9.0.31.jar:9.0.31] 
... 102 common frames omitted 
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /var/myuploads/upload_98120ffe_9eca_4a43_9fe7_c67f4a5f46b7_00000001.tmp (Read-only file system) 
at java.base/java.io.FileOutputStream.open0(Native Method) ~[na:na] 
at java.base/java.io.FileOutputStream.open(FileOutputStream.java:298) ~[na:na] 
at java.base/java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:237) ~[na:na] 
at java.base/java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:187) ~[na:na] 
at org.apache.tomcat.util.http.fileupload.DeferredFileOutputStream.thresholdReached(DeferredFileOutputStream.java:151) ~[tomcat9-coyote-9.0.31.jar:9.0.31] 
at org.apache.tomcat.util.http.fileupload.ThresholdingOutputStream.checkThreshold(ThresholdingOutputStream.java:200) ~[tomcat9-coyote-9.0.31.jar:9.0.31] 
at org.apache.tomcat.util.http.fileupload.ThresholdingOutputStream.write(ThresholdingOutputStream.java:126) ~[tomcat9-coyote-9.0.31.jar:9.0.31] 
at org.apache.tomcat.util.http.fileupload.util.Streams.copy(Streams.java:105) ~[tomcat9-coyote-9.0.31.jar:9.0.31] 
at org.apache.tomcat.util.http.fileupload.FileUploadBase.parseRequest(FileUploadBase.java:293) ~[tomcat9-coyote-9.0.31.jar:9.0.31] 
... 103 common frames omitted 
.w.s.m.s.DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver : Resolved [org.springframework.web.HttpRequestMethodNotSupportedException: Request method 'POST' not supported]
```

I allowed access to the directory, but I'm getting the same error over and over. What could be the problem?

The environment is:

- Java 11
- Springboot 2.75
- Ubuntu 20.04

Comment: Hi, do you find a solution? i have the same issue?